# how to create full functionality of calendar in android?

Tags: android, api, layout, calendar

it seems android calendar api is not available. can you please give me some tips and tricks for creating a similar thing.just like creating events,meeting, birthday etc.. and also notification when the event occurs. and also layout should be similar to-our in-built calendar give me some ideas or hint about look and logic?

Comment: There is a calendar API.

Comment: is it may i know how to implement? any tutorial?

Comment: So basically, you want someone on stackoverflow to tell you how to write a full featured calendar app?  That seems a bit beyond the scope of a single question.  Why don't you go read the Android documentation, try out some things, and come back with a specific question.

Comment: @Mayra: i didn't mean that i want u people to write code for me. as a beginner i even don't know this android has a google calander api.normally i use static layout,but this calender requires dynamic layout. i just asked for a hint or a small idea. if you are interested you can answer it.i hope once upon a time you are also a beginner and seeking for help!

Comment: @Adhavan Its not about being a beginner or not, its about asking good questions. If you can show that you have at least done a basic Google search, and spent 5 minutes thinking about the problem before posting a your question, you will get a lot more useful responses.

Comment: @Marya:when i started my calender idea, i just googled http://blog.funambol.com/2010/05/google-where-is-calendar-api-in-android.html this is the first link i got. this made me to strongly believe that there is no calender api for developers.and its a nightmare for developer! this is the reason i post this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send notifications, read [creating status bar notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

To create layouts, read [declaring layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), [common layout objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html), and [hello GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).  There is an equivalent introductory tutorial for each layout type.

You can access the Calendar events through the [Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html).  However, the Android specific calendar APIs are not part of the public Android SDK.  Thus, you *could* access them, but it is highly recommended that you do not since they are likely to change in future versions of the os.

Comment: @Marys: Thank You for the nice post!now i got the idea that i can use grid layout! ** you could access them** ok let me use that api,**but it is highly recommended that you do not since they are likely to change in future versions of the os.** it seems that i shouldn't use that api. now what should i do use that or not? if i use will it work in next version of android? don't think i am rude, i really went mad with this calender application!

Comment: There are two different APIs mentioned, the Data API is safe to access, but it requires communication with the server.  The Android specific calendar APIs are not safe to use, as there is no guarantee they will be the same in future versions, or on different devices. If you really want to write a full calendar replacement you'd have to use the data APIs.

Comment: @Mayra:its cool. You made me clear.for UI i am gonna use grid layout,when event occurs then its gonna be notification,and when it comes to assing and deleting events then its gonna be services,am i right? still i have a small doubt,if i use data api its is going to be a part of google??? am i sharing my confidential info with google?

Comment: It is no different from putting your information into the google calendar.

Comment: yep i agree! but i don't want to put my information into google calendar.since its my own confidential info!so i can create my own service and link my calendar UI to my service is it possible? but in this case notification is difficult i guess is it? k anyway let me now start with UI part

Comment: If you don't want to use the Google calendar service, then yes you need to create your own service, so I don't know why you would care about a Google calendar sdk.

Comment: @Mayra:Hats off! Thank you for your most valuable post.i create my own grid layout and a small service according to my application need.its working perfect!at first i thought calendar is a nightmare but now with your hint it became a cake-walk. i really believe myself, more than google!;-)